# Laravel Blade passing variable with string through @include causes error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

In Laravel 5.0.27 I am including a view with with a variable and the following code:

```
@include('layouts.article', [
        'mainTitle' => "404, page not found",
        'mainContent' => "sorry, but the requested page does not exist :("
    ])
```

and I get the following error...

> FatalErrorException syntax ... error, unexpected ','

I've narrowed down that the error is solely from the "(" in the "mainContent" variable string, and when I remove the "(" the error disappears and everything runs fine. I can't find anything in documentation on this or any similar errors listed online.

Does anyone know if this is expected behavior or if this is a bug that should be reported?

Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: I not sure for this answer give spacebar to "( "  Could u try ? @joey

Comment: This is seems to be a bug.. It can getting work using some kind of escaping method. but by default It should be work as it is!

Comment: This bug can be reported to the https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues

Comment: Thanks guys, just reported it as a bug on [this issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8502)

Comment: Great find! Could you please answer your question or something so that it is no longer in the php/unanswered list? Thanks!

Comment: Might be a good use of `@component`

Answer (score 159, accepted):

It's not a bug but a limitation of blade syntax due to regex. Solution came from [github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8502):

> The problem is using multi-line. You can only use a single line to
>   [pass variables] in Blade, since syntax is limited [by regular
>   expressions]
>
> Try the code below and you should be good to go:
>
> ```
> @include('layouts.article', ['mainTitle' => "404, page not found", 'mainContent' => "sorry, but the requested page does not exist :("])
> ```

Comment: The limitation seems to be lifted with Laravel `5.6`: https://cloud.mxchange.org/s/149vSQYmDeENiuY/download?path=%2FLaravel%205.6&files=blade-multiline-example.txt

Comment: The issue claims as of 5.6 it still doesn't work but should soon, no update on that issue though if it was implemented https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8502

Answer (score 40):

In [5.8v](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#including-sub-views), included views inherit all variables from the parent as per in documentation:

> Even though the included view will inherit all data available in the parent view, you may also pass an array of extra data to the included view:
>
> ```php
> @include('view.name', ['some' => 'data'])
> ```

Comment: Don't know why people are down-voting it!

Comment: I can not see reason either

Comment: I downvoted this answer because it doesn't address the actual question. The premise of the question is that include breaks with a specific variable inclusion and format, see my github issue for an understanding of it: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8502

Comment: Hi, is it possible to attach some kind of @only keyword to this, to restrict access to the included context?
[I'm asking in relation to the 'only' keyword in twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66819354/twigs-include-with-in-blade-or-regular-php)

Answer (score 30):

> You can pass a $data array

```
<?php $data=[
        'mainTitle' => "404, page not found",
        'mainContent' => "sorry, but the requested page does not exist :("
    ]  ?>
@include('layouts.article', $data)
```

> use `$data['mainTitle']` etc in `layouts.article`

Comment: Please don't do it like this. You don't need php tags in blade files. Not only don't you need $data at all you should do all php processing in the controller.

Comment: you can also use this with `@php` `@endphp` tag from `<?php ... ?>` as to maintain consistency of blade