# How to pass variables to http error layouts in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am going crazy looking for a solution to this. I need to do a very simple thing - pass variables to the custom **404 page** layout. Laravel lets you easily create a custom view for your http errors by creating a file like `/resources/views/errors/404.blade.php` but why doesn't it easily let you pass variables to it?

I tried overwriting `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` render **method:**

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        if($this->isHttpException($e)){
            switch ($e->getStatusCode()) {
                case '404':
                      parent::render($request, $e)->flash();
                      $categories = Category::hierarchy();
                      return View::make('errors.404')->with(['categories' => $categories]);
                break;

                default:
                    return $this->renderHttpException($e);
                break;
            }
        }
        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
```

But for whatever reason this doesn't work and I cannot access the categories variable in my master layout. I'm working on a site that displays header on error pages but if I can't pass variables to the error view then my header cannot be created.

> Undefined variable: categories

Anyone has an idea of what could be going wrong? Is it just impossible to do this? I have read you can pass the exception in and get a message from it but what's the point of that? I don't want to have to duplicate the entire layout and rewrite all variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a View Composer: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#view-composers

Answer (score 1):

i was creating custom error layout(views/error/404.blade.php), (had to pass variable to check if user was logged in or not).
you can use something like this

```
@include('layouts.article', ['mainTitle' => "404, page not found", 'mainContent' => "sorry, but the requested page does not exist :("])
```

or like this

```
<?php $data=[
        'mainTitle' => "404, page not found",
        'mainContent' => "sorry, but the requested page does not exist :("
    ]  ?>
@include('layouts.article', $data)
```

reference: [Laravel Blade passing variable with string through @include causes error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29739745/laravel-blade-passing-variable-with-string-through-include-causes-error)

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
public function boot()
{
  view()->composer('my.view', function($view)
  {
    $view->with('myVariable', 'whatever you want');
  });
}
```

to the `AppServiceProvider.php`

This will pass `whatever you want` as a `$myVariable` to the `view.blade.php` in `my` folder. There might be typos.

More info: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/25 (code at 9:32)

Comment: This will work only for regular views, not for custom error pages.

Answer (score 0):

There some breaking change in 5.4, you should use `::` as delimeter for error views, for example:

```
View::composer('errors::*', function($view){
    $view->with('varName', 'value');
})
```

Comment: But this does not work when rendering views manually through view('404'), so you should use this:
`View::composer(['errors::*', 'errors.*'], function ($view) {`

Answer (score 0):

This trick working for me.

In your controller method:

```
abort(404,json_encode($categories));
```

In your 404.blade.php:

```
@php $categories = json_decode($exception->getMessage()) @endphp

@foreach($categories as $category)...
```