# How can I use variables globally in Blade templates

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want use `$unreadMessages` in my layout but I don't know which controller is used globally for layouts.
It is in `dashboardController`, but I get this error:

> Undefined variable: unreadMessages (View:
>   /myhost/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php) (View: /
>   myhost/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php)

In which controller can I define this variable so I can use it globally?

This code is for `$unreadMessages` in the `dashboardController`:

```
<?php

class DashboardController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        \Artisan::call('status:check');
        $unreadMessages = TicketMessage::where(['is_read' => 0])->whereIn('ticket_id', $ticketIds)->whereNotIn('user_id', [Auth::user()->id])->count();


        return view('dashboard', compact(
            'unreadMessages'
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: That should work just fine. No special controller/model/whatever needed to use variables in a layout page. Are there any unread messages? (`dd($unreadMessages);`)

Comment: tnx but where are I put  _@include('app', array('unreadMessages' => $unreadMessages))_

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel: Where to store global arrays data and constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854030/laravel-where-to-store-global-arrays-data-and-constants)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 - global Blade view variable available in all templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29715813/laravel-5-global-blade-view-variable-available-in-all-templates)

Answer (score 1):

you can resolve this issue by using the following code in  `Route.php` file:

```
view()->share('unreadMessages', $unreadMessages);
```

Comment: My script don't have the Route.php file

Comment: I fund RouteServiceProvider.php, Is it your mean?

Comment: You can locate route.php in \app\Http folder in old version laravel. New version doesn't have any file like route.php. For that their exists a folder named routers and having files named api.php,  console.php and web.php. Put the code in web.php

Comment: For more about routing you can refer https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#basic-routing

Answer (score 0):

In your dashboard.blade.php, there is likely a reference to `@include('layouts/app')` or something similar.  If not, do a search of your code for a reference similar to that.

You'll need to pass `$unreadMessages` to that sub-view.  You are passing it into the main blade (dashboard.blade.php), but not the included blade within dashboard (app.blade.php).

So, you will need something like:

```
@include('layouts/app', array('unreadMessages' => $unreadMessages))
```

Here are a few articles that might assist further:

- [How to include a sub-view in Blade templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21753954/how-to-include-a-sub-view-in-blade-templates)
- [Laravel Blade passing variable with string through @include causes error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29739745/laravel-blade-passing-variable-with-string-through-include-causes-error)
- [global Blade view variable available in all templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29715813/laravel-5-global-blade-view-variable-available-in-all-templates)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a ServiceProvider, in the boot function, for example :

```
 public function boot() {
    ...

    view()->composer(['layouts.app'],function($view) {
        $unreadMessages = TicketMessage::where(['is_read' => 0])->whereIn('ticket_id', $ticketIds)->whereNotIn('user_id', [Auth::user()->id])->count();
        $view->with('unreadMessages',$unreadMessages)
    });
 }
```

Comment: In the AuthServiceProvider (App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider)

Comment: try it with view()->composer('*',function($view) {})