# Cant access variable outside the @include

Tags: php, laravel-blade, laravel-7

Hi everyone I am facing an issue

I was using this layout architecture before and facing this issue

in master.blade.php

```
code.....

@php $foo = "bar"; @endphp

@yield('main')

code ends....
```

in contact.blade.php

```
@extends('master')

code...

@section('main')

@php echo $foo; @endphp

@endsection

code ends...
```

> ERROR: undefined varibale foo in contact.blade.php

.......................................................................

then I switched to the new architecture and again I am facing the same issue.

in master.blade.php

```
code.....

@php $foo = "bar"; @endphp

code ends....
```

in contact.blade.php

```
code...

@includes('master')

@php echo $foo; @endphp

code ends...
```

> ERROR: undefined varibale foo in contact.blade.php

So suggest me what I have to do to access the variable.

Comment: you should have a look at the generated php files in `storage/framework/views` and try to understand what it is actually doing behind the scenes. It will make a lot more sense

Comment: Hi @CornelRaiu thanks for you reply but if there is any thing I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Blade passing variable with string through @include causes error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29739745/laravel-blade-passing-variable-with-string-through-include-causes-error)

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#including-subviews

Comment: No, this link shows that how to pass data into the @include

Comment: check this one out :) https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-blade-variables-into-atyield . Google: "laravel blade pass variable to yield" and it will give you a series of interesting results.

Comment: blade content created from view factory, the data pass the factory and rendered its content as echoed. It is not like the php include. So if you define variable like this, it will be echoed and variable will be undefined

Answer (score 0):

Add
`@php global $foo; @endphp`

in all your blades.

Solve my problem as I'm using a variable in my sub-blade to control what javascript to include (avoiding duplicate) in master.