# Value inside include

Tags: php, laravel-blade

I want to declare the value inside the `include`, so that later I can call it in the file itself

First I do this

```
@include('components.protected-email', ['key' => 'emails[0]'])
```

and in the file itself

```
@php

$split = explode('@', $key);
$first = $split[0];
$second = $split[1];

@endphp
<a href="" data-first="{{ $first }}" data-second="{{ $second }}" class="js-combaine-email"></a>
```

But I get the error

`ErrorException Undefined offset: 1 (View: D:\wamp64\www\test\resources\views\components\protected-email.blade.php)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52218502/2943403  you don't need to split in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a *string* as your `$key` parameter. Your string doesn't contain a `@` character, so `$split = explode('@', $key);` will result in `$split[0]` holding your complete string, since it cannot be exploded. `$split[1]` does not exist so you get

"*ErrorException Undefined offset: 1...*"

Assuming you have `$emails[0]` defined somewhere change

```
@include('components.protected-email', ['key' => 'emails[0]'])
```

to

```
@include('components.protected-email', ['key' => $emails[0]])
```

You also might want to check if `$split[1]` exists before assigning it